# Reference database name in sqlite studio

Tags: sqlite, sqlitestudio

In Sqlite studio, I usually select the database name from the dropdown before executing a query. 
However if I want to specify the database name in the SQL itself, something like

```
  Select * from C:\Folder\DbList\Test.Db \<tableName>.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.
In SQLite, all commands are sent to an opened database, so you must open one *before* you can execute a command.

The `sqlite3` command-line shell has the `.open` command that does not go to the SQL engine, but in SQLite Studio, this must be done with a menu entry.

Comment: Note, that in SQLiteStudio you can use database name (as presented on the left side list) in SQL query and SQLiteStudio will open and attach that database for the time of query execution, like `select * from [my database 1].tableName`. This feature in SQLiteStudio is called transparent attaching.

Answer (score 0):

Having several databases open at sametime in SQLite Studio.
You can access to all of them from the same SQL query window independentely of the value for db in the dropdown menu that you said.

example of selects from 2 databases

```
SELECT  title, body
   FROM myDB_1.Notas
   WHERE ROWID< 20
UNION
SELECT  title, content
    FROM my_DB2.texto
```

Note that score symbol "-" in db name produces errors, so replace it by underscore